# No Longer Possible to Access Bluemix Containers via SSH Key?

Tags: ssh, containers, ibm-cloud, ssh-keys, ibm-cloud-tools

It seems like that Bluemix Containers are now no longer available with SSH key access just like the enclosed picture. What happened?

Could anyone tell me how to restore the SSH key access on Bluemix Containers?

[image: No "SSH Key" section is available.]

Answer (score 0):

Using SSH does not works for me for a while too.

If you have cf ic plugin, do the following,

```
cf ic exec -it <your container name> bash
```

This will allow you to access your container via command prompt.

Answer (score 0):

Originally, the exec command was not supported, and sshd was included in the default image as a means to access the running containers.  When exec became supported, sshd was then unnecessary for most uses, so was removed from the default images to reduce memory/security overhead.

You can still create a custom image/Dockerfile that installs sshd and copies in your own SSH key, either via COPY, or at run time via env var injection, but in general using [cf ic exec](https://console.ng.bluemix.net/docs/containers/container_cli_reference_cfic.html#container_cli_reference_cfic__exec) or `docker exec` for execution access, or [cf ic cp](https://console.ng.bluemix.net/docs/containers/container_cli_reference_cfic.html#container_cli_reference_cfic__cp) / `docker cp` for file copying instead may be a better choice.

Answer (score 0):

If I use "bx" instead of "cf" I can access my container. It worked just now. Hope it helps and the problem was just about accessing a container.

```
bx ic exec -it <your container name> bash
```